# Reuse Storyboard in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, silverlight, storyboard, windows-phone

I've got a `Storyboard` used in my Windows Phone app:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Grid.Row="1">
  <Canvas.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="sb">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
             AutoReverse="True">
               <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0" Value="Black" />
               <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.25" Value="Red" />
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
  </Canvas.Resources>
</Canvas>
```

I've got multiple `Rectangle`s that will be using this `Storyboard`, **but it only seems to work the first time**.

For example, the following code is used to display four different `Rectangles` but only the first one is displayed. The code does not error, but the last 3 `Rectangle`s do not turn red and it appears the `Storyboard` doesn't even run.

```
sb.Stop();
sb.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, myRect1.name);
sb.Begin();

sb.Stop();
sb.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, myRect2.name);
sb.Begin();

sb.Stop();
sb.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, myRect3.name);
sb.Begin();

sb.Stop();
sb.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, myRect4.name);
sb.Begin();
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or know how to get my `Storyboard` to be re-usable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you're doing wrong:

The storyboard execution is asynchronous. When you call the `Storyboard.Begin` method, the storyboard begins in background and your code continues to execute. Therefore, You're calling `Storyboard.Stop` right after starting it! The only one you don't stop is the last one, and that's why it's the only rectangle which color changes.

If you want to chain your animations, you have to subscribe to the `Completed` event to know when the storyboard ends, then restart it for the next controls. Here is one way of doing that:

```
private Rectangle[] ControlsToAnimate;

private int CurrentIndex;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ControlsToAnimate = new[] { this.Rectangle1, this.Rectangle2 };

    this.Storyboard1.Completed += StoryboardCompleted;
    this.AnimateNextControl();
}

private void AnimateNextControl()
{
    if (this.CurrentIndex >= this.ControlsToAnimate.Length)
    {
        this.CurrentIndex = 0;
        return;
    }

    var nextControl = this.ControlsToAnimate[this.CurrentIndex];

    this.CurrentIndex++;

    this.Storyboard1.Stop();
    this.Storyboard1.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, nextControl.Name);
    this.Storyboard1.Begin();
}

private void StoryboardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AnimateNextControl();
}
```

Now, you're going to face two problems:

1. When assigning the storyboard to a new control, the color of the previous control will return to its original value (before the storyboard was started). If you want it to keep its new value, you've got to save it:

   ```
   private void AnimateNextControl()
   {
       if (this.CurrentIndex > 0)
       {
           var brush = (SolidColorBrush)this.ControlsToAnimate[this.CurrentIndex - 1].Fill;
           brush.Color = brush.Color;
       }

       if (this.CurrentIndex >= this.ControlsToAnimate.Length)
       {
           this.CurrentIndex = 0;
           return;
       }

       var nextControl = this.ControlsToAnimate[this.CurrentIndex];

       this.CurrentIndex++;

       this.Storyboard1.Stop();
       this.Storyboard1.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, nextControl.Name);
       this.Storyboard1.Begin();
   }
   ```
2. You can't animate two controls at the same time using a single storyboard. If you want to animate all your rectangles at the same time, you need to use one storyboard per control.

Comment: Thanks! As for the problems I'll face, the fact that the color of the previous control will go back to normal before starting the next storyboard is perfectly fine. I just want to turn it red, then back to black. I also won't need to animate two controls at the same time using this storyboard. I'll give this a try using your example by using the `Completed` event.

Comment: Yup, this seems to be what I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Once again I must make my comment an answer since I still cannot comment apparently.

Are you attempting to run these all concurrently? I do believe that only a single instance of a XAML defined storyboard exists so you may not be able to reuse it on multiple controls at the same time.

If all else fails you can just create a UserControl with a rectangle containing the storyboard which you CAN reuse. That code sample I provided on your previous question is from a Tile that flips using a storyboard. Since its a usercontrol, I can have as many tiles as I want flipping at the same time.

Comment: Nope, I don't need to run them concurrently.